# Code for Silex check_path to validate a user login

Tags: php, silex

I am currently following the Silex tutorial on [Security Service Provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html).

I have the login form working, with my check_path set to /login_check using this code:

```php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/contacts/add',
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'users' => array(
                'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
            ),
        )
    )
));
```

However, I do not know how to validate a user login in silex as there is no example code for login_check:

```php
$app->post('/login_check', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    // What now??
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Silex/Symfony will process the authentication check for you so you will get no hook at the route `/login_check`, but you can add a handler which will be called by Silex after a successfull login:

```
$app['security.authentication.success_handler.admin'] = 
  $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler($app['security.http_utils'], 
    array(), $app);
  });
```

The CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends the [DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) (Example):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Silex\Application;

class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
  protected $app = null;

  public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, Application $app)
  {
    parent::__construct($httpUtils, $options);
    $this->app = $app;
  }

  public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
  {
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $data = array(
        'last_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    // save the last login of the user
    $this->app['account']->updateUserData($user->getUsername(), $data);

    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));
  }
}
```

in this example `onAuthenticationSuccess()` update the user data and log the datetime of the last login - you can perform any other action there.

There exists also handler for authentication failure and logout.

Comment: I don't understand your return clause, but it works fine !